# xsl:template match for xml with prefixes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xls, transformation

I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bo:C837ClaimParent xsi:type="bo:C837ClaimParent"     
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns:bo="http://somelongpathHere/process/bo">
<claimAux>
...
</claimAux>
<enterpriseClaim>
...
    <patientAccountNumber>data to capture here</patientAccountNumber>
</enterpriseClaim>
```

I need to match the data inside <patientAccountNumber>, which is inside <enterpriseClaim>, which is inside <bo:C837ClaimParent>
    I have tried all the values I can think of on the xsl:template match and I cannot match that node, it either doesn't find it, or matches the entire xml file, my xsl file looks as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
....
<div>
  <xsl:value-of select="C837ClaimParent/enterpriseClaim/patientAccountNumber" /></div>
```

what do I need to specify on my xsl:template and my xsl:value-of ?

also, for this same file I will be matching other values, everything is inside the main node <bo:C837ClaimParent, so what do I need to use so that I can efficiently match nodes throughout my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a namespace declaration for your `bo` prefix. This namespace will probably have to appear in your solution unless you use `local-name()`

**edit** (after namespace appeared!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:bo="http://somelongpathHere/process/bo">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
....
<div>
  <xsl:value-of select="bo:C837ClaimParent/enterpriseClaim/patientAccountNumber" /></div>
```

Are you sure that `enterpriseClaim` is in a different namespace from `C837ClaimParent`?

Comment: sorry, I fixed the formatting problems, had many problems getting it right on the editor

Comment: that did it, adding the namespace, now how do I avoid having to specify that prefix on every single select, is that efficient?

Comment: You cannot avoid the prefix. In XML, it's possible to have a default namespace (with no prefix), but in XPath, no prefix always means empty namespace (i.e. with no URI). This does not affect efficiency in any way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:bo="http://www.bo.org">
   ...
   <xsl:value-of select="/bo:C837ClaimParent/enterpriseClaim/patientAccountNumber" />
   ...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In general, my advice would be to read up on namespaces in XML and XPath.

Comment: I have tried that already, I get this error: "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'bo'"

Comment: Please note the `xmlns:bo` declaration on `<xsl:stylesheet>`!

Comment: @Pavel note he has added a different namespace for bo from yours